# IPv6 Spams dataset?

Tags: email, spam, ipv6, information-gathering

My master thesis is about "Managing Spam Under IPv6". I would like to use machine learning algorithm on information retrieved from mail headers in order to sort out spams from legitimate mails. To do my testings I obviously need a huge dataset of spams and legitimate emails (hams). Unfortunately I have been unable to find a large enough dataset of IPv6 spams and legitimate emails (hams) on internet datasets. Does anyone know of such a dataset in the public domain?

Alternatively, any ideas in order to create my own dataset would be greatly appreciated! Are there any researchers who work in this domain that I could contact?

For now I am basically using gmail spams from some friends of me, I can find few ipv6 spams but the amount I need is much larger if I want exploitable results from the machine learning ...

PS: I know this is not the best kind of question to ask on steckexchange, since it leads more to an open discussion, but I really need help and this is for the sake of science so please be indulgent ^^

Comment: Hi @Vrael and welcome to security.stackexchange! I took a bunch of text our of your question to make it shorter and easier to read. If you don't like my edit, you can roll it back by going [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/155842/revisions).

Comment: What's unique about IPv6 as a delivery mechanism for spam? Aren't all the interesting bits on the application layer?

Comment: @schroeder IP address reputation management becomes trickier since IPv6 addresses are cheap and you can't easily tell how big a subnet is given to each user.

Comment: @CodesInChaos sure, but how then do you run ML on such a vast data range to come up with a reputation model? You aren't going to get anything interesting by inspecting network addresses.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your interest. No problem for the edit. 

I am working on the network edge, and not on the mail content itself (no bayes filter). What is unique is the fact that they are too many ipv6 adresses to perform good black listings, BL will be too long, and spammers can change of ip adress for nearly each spam if they want too. 

@Co

Comment: @schroeder  Check this link https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/hao.pdf In this paper they use simple features like AS origin, message length, time of sending, .... I d like to see if it still good under ipv6, that is what I want to use for ML